# Challenge: Make background and two div elements scale and move relative to browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take what is here:

http://test.thebkk.net

and make it scale and fit to any browser window, maintaining position of the elements and keeping the image completely in the window.

CSS involving positioning etc.:

```
body {
       background-color: black;
       background-image: url('http://thebkk.net/Images/BVF-Temp.jpg');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: 45px -30px;
}

/* Player Style */
#player {
      position: fixed;
      width: 680px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-left: 350px;
      border: outset 5px white;
}
ul#menu {
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: 12px; 
      margin-left: 90px;
      padding: 0; 
      list-style: none;
      clear: both;     
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realize the menu is wonky, it is a test sprite menu, first run, have a sharper one, may be up by the time you are checking this.

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size: 100% auto;` (w/h) and thinks should work. for everything else use percentage widths (and heights) and positions as well

Comment: This did nothing to the size.  I have also tried `background-size: contain;` which did not alter the size either...using most recent Chrome/Firefox to check my site.  Also checking on Linux/Mac/Windows.  As is, is exactly how I want it, just want it to be centered and scale to any browser window size.

Comment: background-size does only work together with a background-image:url() declaration - maybe that wasn't clear enough in my comment